# Java - How to Implement socket ping between two java programs on same host

Tags: java, sockets

I am writing two java programs that will communicate some information between them. I am running both of them on the same host.

I need to establish a pinging mechanism between them to identify if both of them are alive at any given point of time. I am guessing Java Socket programming is the best way to do this. But confused on how to differentiate between the programs when they run on the same localhost IP address (127.0.0.1).

Comment: If you run them as a web service that can accept incoming HTTP requests, each one will consume at least one port (ie `8080` and `8081`). Write a small script that periodically call `http://localhost:8080` and `https://localhost:8081` and validate that the resonse is HTTP 200.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. I will try that also. Just wanted to know if there is a way using socket programming ? Like binding a ip and port to a socket and then use InetAddress methods ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create two sockets on two differents ports :

Ping B to A :

Application A :

```
ServerSocket socketA = new ServerSocket(socketPortA);
Socket socketB=socketA.accept(); //awaiting other application to "come"
byte ping=socketB.getInputStream().read();
```

Application B :

```
Socket toA=new Socket("127.0.0.1",socketPortA); //connect to A
toA.getOutputStream().write(1);
```